# AngularJS - Showing different divs based on the ng-if result

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've got a simple chat app in `AngularJS`, and I'm sending a `message` to the view which is being outputted on the front end like this:

```
<div id="messages" class="col-xs-12 chat-messages">
    <div class="col-xs-12 chat-message" ng-repeat="message in chatMessages">

        <div class="you">
            <ul class="media-list">
                <li class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <div class="media-object img-circle" style="background-image: url( {{message.avatar_url}} )"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="media-heading text-muted small">
                            {{message.nickname}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-content bubble">
                            {{message.content}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment I am just going through the `chatMessages` array and outputting them using this div. I have given each message another attribute of `kind` where I will send to the view different kinds of messages, such as `userMe`, `userOther`, `global` etc. and I will need to use a slightly different HTML markup for each `kind` of message. I understand that this should be done using `ng-if` in AngularJS, but I don't quite know how to go about this.

From the view, I will need to output some different HTML depending on the `message.kind` value.

Any ideas?

Comment: `<div ng-if="message.kind === 'userMe'">do something</div>`

Comment: @Tom Maybe I was making some stupid errors, I'll try that again. You should be able to just include 3 `ng-if` blocks in the same `ng-repeat` right?

Comment: have you tried `ng-switch` ?https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: @ArtemPetrosian This seems more logical from a syntax point of view so that it's easier to understand, but would it make a difference?

Comment: @germainelol it is always make sense when you can make your code more logical or easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have several possible div options for each element, I'd use [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch), like Tom said in the comments.

The idea is that you switch on the `message.kind`, or whatever you want to switch on, and have each `div` as a "Case" for that:

It would look something like this:

```
<div class="media-body"  ng-switch="message.kind">
        <div class="media-heading text-muted small"  ng-switch-when="1">
              {{message.nickname}}
        </div>
        <div class="message-content"  ng-switch-when="2">
              {{message.content}}
        </div>
        <div class="message-content bubble"  ng-switch-default>
              default text
        </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13878/)

Comment: Thanks, the other answer works just as well, but I think this is more logical and similar in syntax to a switch statement

Answer (score 1):

You have two solution to archieve what you want :

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages">
    <div ng-if="msg.kind === 'userMe'">userMeMessage</div>
    <div ng-if="msg.kind === 'global'">globalMessage</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Or this :

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages|filter:{kind:'userMe'}">
  UserMe
</div>
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages|filter:{kind:'global'}">
  Global
</div>
```

Comment: There are also the [ngMessage](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessage) and [ngMessages](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) directives in Angular 1.3+

Comment: @Sly_cardinal Sweet, didn't know this one. Not sure if it's adapted to this use case, but thx for pointing it out !